# Renaming downloaded YT videos with the youtube-dl

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, youtube-dl

I have a link list with names in the first column and links in the last column. I want to write a script that downloads the files and names the file according to the first column.
My code is

> #!/bin/bash
>   x="/group/cgl/2018/04/list.dat"
>
> title=$(awk '{print $1}' $x)
>
> Parameter=$(awk '{print $NF}' $x)
>
> youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 -o "%("$title")s.%(ext)s" $Parameter

it is able to download and convert the files to mp3 if i leave the

> -o "%("$title")s.%(ext)s"

out. Whats wrong with this code, it gives me the error

> youtube-dl: error: Cannot download a video and extract audio into the same file! Use "%(heuteXpress.%(ext)s" instead of "%(heuteXpress" as the output template

but fixing it like that doesnt solve it and gives a simmilar error.

Answer (score 2):

The `-o` option defines an output *template*. In an output template, everything in the parentheses in `%(...)s` is the name of a key.

To add a verbatim text into a template, just write it out, masking `%` characters with another percent sign, like this:

```
-o "$(echo "$title" | sed 's/%/%%/g').%(ext)s"
```

For more information, refer to the [official documentation on output templates](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template).